# Docker container DNS - Resolve URL

Tags: docker, dns

I have a docker container that needs to access an network server on the LAN. This server is visible from the docker host machine and I can access it from within the container when I reference the IP address directly.

However I need to be able to specify a url and port (e.g http://myserver:8080) rather than an IP address, which the docker container cannot resolve.

How can I configure the container to resolve this? ideally using the docker hosts dns. I have looked at many of the docs, but not being a DNS expert, it doesn't seem straightforward.

UPDATE:
I have tried this, which seems to work, but does this have any downsides or unintended consequences?

```
--network host
```

Thanks,

Comment: That should be fine; I guess if you want to see other docker containers you will have to join the bridge network as well.

Comment: For this I have no need to see any other containers, but conformable with this by creating a custom network and adding both containers to it - although not sure how you would do both - but no need in this case - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The rigth way to do this is to configure the docker daemon dns as specified under [daemon-dns-options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-dns-options).

Using the host network is not recommended as it has some downsides https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: Just come across the --dns flag in the 'docker run' command. Would this effectively do the same as above but at an individual container level?

Comment: @MikeJ yes, this should work, however you will have to set it on each container that you start